# Convert strConflictedYesReviewers data into a single object which is grouped by ownerid and make array of opportunityid

Tags: javascript, strings

I get a dynamic string(strConflictedYesReviewers) which contains multiple user recordswhere each record is separated by semicolon and then each record represents ownerid and opportunityid separated by asterisk.

I have done it but looking for a better approach or code review.

```js
const strConflictedYesReviewers = "88639280*198719943;88642547*198721749;88627345*198721749;88664734*198721749;88686221*198721749;88676217*198721749;88664734*198721749;88686221*198721749;88676217*198721749;"
.split(";")
.map(item => item.split("*"))     
.filter(item => !!item[0])
.map(item => ({ownerid: item[0], opportunityid: item[1]}))
.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  (acc[curr["ownerid"]] = acc[curr["ownerid"]] || []).push(curr["opportunityid"]);
  return acc;
}, {});
   

console.log(strConflictedYesReviewers);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over the generated array needlessly when creating the intermediate objects since you throw away those objects in the reducer.

If the filtering is there just for the final `;`-split, and you can assume you will always have both datum, you can drop the whole filtering by removing `/;$/` from the string beforehand — saving another iteration. If you know for sure the string will always have the final `;`, a `slice` would be efficient.

It’s often a good idea to separate the reducer and give it a descriptive name, for example:

```
const byOwner = (acc, [owner, opportunity]) =>
  ((acc[owner] ||= []).push(opportunity), acc)
```

*(Please note the stylistic choices here, of which many would advice against. Such as the comma operator, lack of semicolons, braces, and explicit `return`. Perhaps even the somewhat recent logical OR assignment.)*

so the usage becomes clean `<iterable>.reduce(byOwner, {})` (although, there is codependence between what you are reducing into, and the inside of the reducer).

If the filtering really is for the possible empty `ownerid`s, then each additional iteration naturally increases runtime. One concept which combines the ease of use of the small mapping and filtering functions while keeping down the iterations (without requiring a bloated reducer), is a **[transducer](https://dev.to/romanliutikov/understanding-transducers-in-javascript-4pdg)**:

```
const compose = f => g => a => f(g(a))

const filtering = pred => reducer => (acc, x) =>
  pred(x) ? reducer(acc, x) : acc

const mapping = fun => reducer => (acc, x) =>
  reducer(acc, fun(x))

const xform = compose
  (filtering (([x]) => x))
  (mapping (x => x.split("*")))
```

so the usage becomes `str.split(";").reduce(xform(byOwner), {})`.

The benefit isn’t going to be apparent on small lists or simple transducers, though.

Comment: txs for the suggestion. Can you explain your statement after => ((acc[owner] ||= []).push(opportunity), acc) becuase I am getting an "Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method." error on my end. txs

Comment: @KarimAli You are probably trying to iterate the objects returned from your `map`ing, which are not iterable (as such), so just remove the line `.map(item => ({ownerid: ...}))` as the reducer is expecting an array of arrays. That was the point of my first paragraph in the answer.

Comment: Txs, really Appreciated.